# rewrite require to import statement

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6, commonjs

I am trying to use https://www.npmjs.com/package/json-bigint with native BigInt support. In CommonJS I'd do:

```
var JSONbigNative = require('json-bigint')({ useNativeBigInt: true });
```

What is the ES6 syntax equivalent? This is not working:

```
import  * as JSONBigIntWrapper from 'json-bigint';
const JSONBigInt = JSONBigIntWrapper({useNativeBigInt: true});
```

as it complains that JSONBigIntWrapper is not a function.

What are the generic rules for rewriting rewrite to import?

Comment: Why the `* as`?

Comment: Typescript expects `allowSyntheticDefaultImports` flag if you want to omit `* as`. Does it make a difference?

Comment: does this work? `const JSONBigInt = JSONBigIntWrapper.default({ useNativeBigInt: true });`

Comment: `Property 'default' does not exist on type 'JSONBigExport'.`

Comment: If `import JSONBigIntWrapper from 'json-bigint'` and `import * as JSONBigIntWrapper from 'json-bigint'` don't work, there might be something wrong with the package or package's types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With ES6 imports, importing `*` is not the equivalent of what `require()` does.

What you are looking to get is the default module export, as shown in the code below

```js
import whatever_you_want_the_default_to_be_named, {} from 'json-bigint'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can rely on using the `default` keyword when importing the default export from a module.

```ts
import {default as _JBI} from 'json-bigint';
const JSONBigNative = _JBI({useNativeBigInt: true});
```

This is also the *only* syntax which works when using [dynamic import syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import#dynamic_imports):

```ts
const {default: _JBI} = await import('json-bigint');
const JSONBigNative = _JBI({useNativeBigInt: true});
```